# Access and refresh dataTable after getting data

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee-6

I have got some problems with my JSF page, and (probably) with backing bean. I have got own template and I fill the content area with some pages. I have got search page with commandbutton and I would like to get data from database (JPA) and than fill the datatable.
Look at my searchpeople.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="template.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="sampleform">  
            <p:accordionPanel activeIndex="-1" id="accordingpanle">  
                <p:tab title="User options" >   
                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" showSummary="true"/> 
                    <p:commandButton id="searchbutton" action="#{mb_person.search}" value="Szukaj" update="personsearchresulttable" />
                </p:tab>
            </p:accordionPanel>

            <p:dataTable id="personsearchresulttable" var="person" value="#{mb_person.people}" widgetVar="personTable" style="margin-top: 10px" >  
                <p:column headerText="Id" style="width:10%">
                    <h:outputText value="#{person.id}" />  
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:20%">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{person.name}" />  
                </p:column>  
                <p:column headerText="Surname" style="width:20%">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{person.surname}" />  
                </p:column>  
                <p:column headerText="Company">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{person.companyName}" />  
                </p:column> 
                <p:column style="width:4%" headerText="Open">  
                    <h:link outcome="persondetails" value="Open">
                        <!--<f:param name="personid" value="#{person.id}"/>-->
                        <f:param name="personid" value="10076"/>
                    </h:link>
                </p:column>  
            </p:dataTable>  
        </h:form>  
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

And my backingbean with EJB injection.

```
@ManagedBean(name="mb_person")
public class MB_Person implements Serializable{

    @EJB
    private PersonFacade personFacade;
    private List<PersonAndCompany> people = new ArrayList<PersonAndCompany>();

    public MB_Person() {
    }

    public List<PersonAndCompany> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(List<PersonAndCompany> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

    public void search() {
        int[] range = {0,5};
        setPeople(personFacade.findPersonWithMoreThanXProjects(20));
        setPeople(personFacade.findPersonAndCompanyName(range));

        for(PersonAndCompany p:people){
            System.out.println(p.getName());
        }
    }
    public String goToPersonDatailPage(int id){
        return "persondetails.jsf?personid="+id;
    }
}
```

I tried small test and printout all data in method search and I received good results.
Someone can help me how to update dataTable using ajax? In this form I have got an exception
**Cannot find component with identifier "personsearchresulttable" referenced from "sampleform:accordingpanle:searchbutton".**

Comment: I know, I rebuild, redeploy, restart server, a lot of times, I try to open page in chorme, safari, in the chrome incognito window and still the same effect - it's not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative client IDs are searched relative to parent [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) component. The [`<p:accordionPanel>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/component/accordionpanel/AccordionPanel.html) is by itself a `NamingContainer`. So the relative client ID `personsearchresulttable` would be searched inside the context of the `<p:accordionPanel>`. However, it's actually outside the panel, inside the `<h:form>`.

You need to change the relative client ID to be an absolute client ID.

```
update=":sampleform:personsearchresulttable"
```

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)